# Word for "separating a group of similar-but-not-the-same things into categories"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing up the changes I have made to some software; said changes include separating some things into categories (I'm trying to avoid making this readable only to people who know about programming).

I am calling these categories *domains* (in the sense of "a sphere of activity," as definition 4 in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/domain)), because software...

My current wording is

> Separated the state and functions into the domains A, B, C, and D.

("State" and "functions" are programming things, but I believe it should still be completely understandable to the folks here on ELU.)

Is there a better word I can use in place of *separate* here? **The sense is that there was a collection of things that are actually different but were still all together, and I have separated them into different groups.** It also needs to express (as best it can) the fact that they were mixed together and that that was not ideal.

For clarity, I am considering "the state and functions" as a single set. The state in this case is a collection of component parts. So I have changed `Everything = { valueA, functionA, valueB, valueC, functionC }` (for example) to `A = { valueA, functionA }`, `B = { valueB }`, `C = { valueC, functionC }`.

The document is documentation for me and other programmers; it can be an uncommon/niche word if necessary.

I have considered/am considering:

- *Separate*
  What I was going to use.
  In the sense:

  - "to divide into constituent parts" or "to isolate from a mixture" - Sense 5, Transitive verb, [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/separate)
  - "to divide into different parts or groups; to divide things into different parts or groups" - Sense 1, Verb, [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/separate_2)
- *Divide*
  My original runner-up.
  In the 1st or 3rd sense as given by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divide):

  - 1.a. "to separate into two or more parts, areas, or groups"
  - 1.b. "to separate into classes, categories, or divisions"
  - 3.a. "to cause to be separate, distinct, or apart from one another"

  Or the 1st sense given by [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/divide_1): "to separate into parts; to make something separate into parts"
- *Partition*
  Seems to be more like simply splitting something up, like sharing out a cake. Same issue with *split up*.

  - "to divide into parts or shares" - [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partition)
  - "to divide something into parts" - [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/partition_2)
- *Isolate*
  This makes it feel more like I isolated the "state and functions" from *something else*, not *each other*.

  - "to set apart from others" - Sense 1, Verb, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isolate)
  - "to separate somebody/something physically or socially from other people or things" - Sense 1, Verb, [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/isolate)
  - "to separate a part of a situation, problem, idea, etc. so that you can see what it is and deal with it separately" - Sense 2, Verb, [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/isolate)
- *Distinguish* (suggested by @WeatherVane)
  Captures the nuance of what I'm trying to express, but seems to be usually defined as *noticing* or *understanding* but not necessarily *acting* upon it (Merriam-Webster is the exception here). Also, I am not sure how exactly I would use this in my case. But otherwise a good choice!

  - "to notice or understand the difference between two things" or "to recognize or understand the difference between two things" - [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/distinguish)
  - "to perceive a difference in" - Sense 1, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distinguish)
  - "to mark as separate or different" - Sense 2.a., [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distinguish)
  - "to separate into kinds, classes, or categories" - Sense 2.b., [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distinguish)
  - "to recognize the difference between two people or things" - Sense 1, [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/distinguish)

I also considered *categorize* and *classify*, but those seem to be more about how something is considered than an actual act. In the context of software (at least in my experience), they are very likely to refer to some sort of labeling, not only an act of grouping (especially *classify*). In this particular case that distinction is important.
In a sense, there are three levels:

- Simply how something is considered, how it is mentally regarded
- How something is concretely *labeled*
- How something is physically *arranged*, which usually implies some sort of labeling as well.

This instance is the third case.

The thesaurus entries I looked at on Merriam-Webster didn't provide anything I could consider using that I have not included here.

*Separate* seems to best capture the nuance of "untangling" the things and "isolating" them from each other, but I would like to know if there is a better-suited word.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144859/discussion-on-question-by-darryl-noakes-word-for-separating-a-group-of-similar); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: As the question stands, I have accepted _group_ as the answer. I am also using _distinguish_ and _divide_ in the same section of the document, so thanks to @WeatherVane for suggesting _distinguish_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So I have changed `Everything = { valueA, functionA, valueB, valueC, functionC }` (for example) to `A = { valueA, functionA }, B = { valueB }, C = { valueC, functionC }`.

Looks like you have **grouped** the values and functions (by "domain"?)

## group

> *verb*
> put in a group or groups
> ...
>
> - put into categories; classify.
>   "molluscs are grouped into seven different classes"

Definitions from Oxford Languages.

I'm very sure I've heard this used for exactly your case too, in the context of refactoring, but I wasn't able to find an example online to point you to.

> Grouped the state and functions into the domains A, B, C, and D.

To me as a programmer, this strongly implies that the values have been collected according to some common denominator.

Answer (score 21):

I washed my red shirt with my white socks.

> ***They were mixed together and that was not ideal.***

Now I have pink socks! Next time I will **sort** my laundry . . .

> **sort**, *v.<sup>1</sup>*
> **II.** Senses relating to arranging or placing in order, and related uses.
> **9. a.** *transitive*.
>  To arrange (things, etc.) according to kind or quality, or after some settled order or system; to separate
> and put into different sorts or classes; to classify; to assort.
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

tl;dr:

> ***Sorted state and functions into the domains A, B, C, and D.***

Comment: I think this could be what I end up using, thanks! I'll see if anything else comes up before I need to finalize my draft; if not, I'll accept this.

Comment: Now we're ELULA... English Language, Usage, and Laundry Advice.

Comment: Sorting, though, usually has a narrower meaning (arranging the elements of a sequence according to some total order) in software.

Comment: @chepner — Above, the OP, a human, is doing the sorting, not the software.

Comment: Yes, but the target audience will likely have the narrower definition in mind.

Comment: @chepner — It seems to me that the target audience is the boss or other humans (“I'm writing up the changes I have made”), who have the latitude to think about sorting not as sequencing but as classification. Forks, knives, spoons...

Answer (score 14):

**Classify**

from Cambridge Dictionary

> to divide things or people into groups according to their type, or to say which group or type something or someone belongs to

This word is often used in machine learning, clustering algorithms, quality checks, etc. where objects have to be sorted or distinguished  depending on some key properties.

Therefore:

> Classified state and functions into the domains A, B, C, and D.

Answer (score 7):

The state and functions were previously disorganised, so now you have **organised** them.

> to do or arrange something according to a particular system:
>
> > The books were organized on the shelves according to their size.

**Source:** [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/organize)

This fits in your change description fine:

> Organised state and functions into the domains A, B, C, and D.

Although you may prefer something like:

> Organised state and functions by domain (A, B, C, or D).

Answer (score 6):

I'd encourage you to revisit *categorise* (or *-ize* if you prefer).

It has the definition of placing into groups [(Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/categorize):

> to arrange in categories or classes; classify

or  [(Cambridge, which is rare in using "the same")](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/categorize?q=categorise):

> to put people or things into groups with the same features

This works best assuming that there's a logical connection between the items in each of your domains/sets - but presumably that's why you're doing it.

Comment: I have considered and reconsidered it quite a few times, but my feeling is that it could be ambiguous; in the context of software (at least in my experience), it is just as likely to refer to some sort of labeling, not an act of grouping. And in this particular case that is an important distinction (which I'll add to the question). But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

---

### Arrange

> to put a group of objects in a particular order

What you did may be considered an *arrangement*.

Therefore, you may want to use

> Arranged state and functions into the domains A, B, C, and D.

**Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arrange)**

Answer (score 4):

## partition

Is good for this, and very domain-appropriate, even though you don't seem to like it right now.

You are exactly splitting up a cake. Sounds like you are starting from some large file, moving all the code in that file that has raisins to another file, and all the code that has icing to another file.

Especially in the programming world, the word reminds of partitioning tasks, e.g. the famous *partition problem*, which typically involve dividing *incongruent* items into different containers.

There is a computer-assistant refactoring tool called the [Acellere Gamma Partitioning Tool](https://embold.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Gamma_Partitioning_CaseStudy.pdf), [this other paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1607208)  (Automated refactoring of objects for application partitioning) uses "partition" to talk about refactoring too, at least one SO question [uses 'partition' to describe the type of refactor he wants to do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22213178/3310334). There are more examples, and I wanted to post an even longer list here to prove you can use the word like this, but it's such a popular word in the CompSci world I actually found it hard to filter my searches down to the case you have at hand (rather than e.g. hard drive partitions or partitioning algorithms). I think developers love this word and will understand according to almost any meaning you intend it to have.

Because of your cake analogy, you seem to dislike that this word connotes starting from one unified whole, but I don't think it actually does. It does seem to more often be used for that, but there are related words like *repartition* with the same etymological roots that are explicitly about dividing discrete "already-divided" things

> 1550s, "partition, distribution," especially of troops or their quarters, from re-, here perhaps intensive, + partition (n.). From 1835 as "a repeated or fresh allotment."

(from etymonline)

and other usages of partition itself that are analogous to your case

> This complex petroleum mixture is expected to partition primarily to soil and/or sediment.

from linguee

> ... his dominions were quickly partitioned between Poland, Denmark and Sweden.

> King Augustus had explained to him a project for partitioning the trans-Baltic provinces of Sweden, by which Poland should recover Livonia and annex Esthonia, Russia should obtain Ingria and Karelia, and Denmark should take possession of Holstein.

from sentence.yourdictionary.com

Answer (score 3):

## Refactored

From a programmer's point of view, it sounds like you have refactored some code to implement the Single Responsibility Principal (the S in SOLID). If the wording you need is for a technical audience then I would suggest you use the appropriate technical language.

See the [Code Refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) article over on Wikipedia. Here are the first 2 sentences of the article:

> In computer programming and software design, code refactoring is the process of restructuring existing computer code—changing the factoring—without changing its external behavior. Refactoring is intended to improve the design, structure, and/or implementation of the software (its non-functional attributes), while preserving its functionality.

You can use Refactored in your original sentence or use it alone if you do not wish to go in to detail.

> Refactored the state and functions into the domains A, B, C, and D.

Comment: @Heartspring Done

Comment: I did consider _refactor_. While it does apply, I feel it is more broad than what I am trying to say. I consider the change I made to be _a_ refactor, but I want a word that conveys the specific sense of what I have actually done. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: I would use refactored here. "refactored" is a generic verb meaning to change code around in a way that is apparent only to programmers but not to end users but you can make it more specific with usage like "refactored x for/to y" e.g. "I refactored the sorting code for time efficiency". In your case it would be "I refactored the state and functions to be grouped by domain" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

**Segregate** as in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/segregate) means:

> to keep one thing separate from another.

> to keep one group of people apart from others because of race, religion, sex, etc.

And an [example](https://jessa-gavila.medium.com/python-sample-quiz-18a257442c8b) from programming context.

> Also, I can no longer segregate codes into blocks like in Colab where I can run it separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that you **disaggregated** them. [MW defines this verb as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disaggregate)

> to separate into component parts

Answer (score 1):

You could say that you **clustered** them into domains A, B, C and D. Clustering things in the data analysis or machine learning sense is when you put points together (in the same cluster) that are more similar to each other than to other points (in other clusters). Points in the same cluster are normally not identical. They all typically have some scatter.

Answer (score 1):

I'll quickly make my comment an answer. I think the words you were using are the best solution:

"Before, functions and state were **lumped** together; I have now **separated** them into these two **categories**." (Or, perhaps, "separated these two categories into two [lists, directories, whatever]".)

Comment: Just for clarity, I am considering "the state and functions" as a single set, unit, whatever. The state in this case is a collection of component parts. So I have changed `Everything = [valueA, functionA, valueB, valueC, functionC]` (for example) to `A = [valueA, functionA]`, `B = [valueB]`, `C = [valueC, functionC]` (_not_ psudeo code, just a diagram).

Answer (score 1):

## segment

> *verb*
> to separate or divide into segments.

it's extra nice because its noun form connotes

> **segment** *noun* one of the parts into which something naturally separates or is divided

(both from dictionary.com)

> Segmented the state and functionality into domains A, B, C, and D.

Comment: Ooh, I really like this one! Must have missed it in my thesaurus search.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I like it too, I think it works well here. Google Dictionary and Thesaurus didn't have its verb form nor suggest it as a synonym to any of its synonyms, which was strange, because it's [quite popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=segmented%2Cpartitioned&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). As a fellow programmer, the word I would use myself for your case is "group"

Answer (score 1):

#### Coarse and fine partitions

It appears that you already had a categorisation/division/partition, but you decided that too many different things were lumped together: the partition was too ***coarse*** and you needed a ***finer*** partition.

In mathematics and more specifically in topology, this is exactly the vocabulary we use: we make a distinction between [finer and coarser topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies#Definition). The finest topology is the discrete topology, that isolates all points; and the coarsest topology is the trivial topology, that lumps all points together.

Answer (score 1):

## Subdivide

May I suggest *Subdivide*?

**Subdivide**: to divide something into smaller parts. (per [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/subdivide))

Usage:

> Subdivided the state and functions into the domains A, B, C, and D.

Comment: As an interesting note, _subdivide_ was the very first word I used, until I started looking into it. However, apart from maybe more definitely implying that there are resulting subdivisions, I don't see _too_ much difference between it and _divide_. I'm still considering _separate_, but at this point will probably use _group_ along with an explantory note.

Comment: I'd say the default meaning of 'subdivide' is as that given at [Oxford Languages {via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=subdivide+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=subdivide+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l2j0i22i30l7.6875j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8): << **subdivide**
[verb]
# divide (something that has already been divided or that is a separate unit).
 • _the heading was subdivided into eight separate sections_ >> Also given as the default definition by M-W, Collins, Dictionary.com, Longman, Macmillan, AHD, R H K Websters.

Answer (score 0):

I (a programmer) tend to use 'allocate' for such things though the word 'sort' is more correct in terms of meaning. In a programming context 'sort' tends to imply an ordering.

Comment: While I do agree that it tends to imply an ordering, I think the _into_ clears it of any ambiguity. For example, I can sort my mail into the piles "family", "business", and "junk mail."

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good choices.  I think your original "separate" is ok.  I like "organize", ""arrange", and "group" a bit better.  I like "partition" even better for this particular use.  Or for an option that hasn't already been offered, I like **split** about as well as "partition".  [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/split) (transitive, 3b):

> to divide into factions, parties, or groups

Answer (score 0):

sub·cat·e·go·rize
[ˌsəbˈkadəɡəˌrīz]
VERB
split into secondary or subordinate categories:
"operations were subcategorized into cardiac and vascular procedures"

We can categorize vehicles into cars and trucks, and we can further subcategorize cars into sedans, coupes, and station wagons.

Comment: You should include the source of the definition for the word.

Comment: I have considered _categorize_ and _subcategorize_. As I stated at the end of my question: while _categorize_ does apply in some sense, it seems to be more about how something is considered than an actual act. But thanks anyway for trying!